# Apache Superset API Request rison filters for nested attributes on permission resources

Tags: apache-superset

I am attempting to apply filters to the permissions-resources API endpoint.

The `_info` endpoint shows these are the possible filter options:

```
api/v1/security/permissions-resources/_info?q=(keys:!(filters))

{"filters"=>
  {"permission"=> [
    {"name"=>"Relation", "operator"=>"rel_o_m"},
    {"name"=>"No Relation", "operator"=>"nrel_o_m"}
  ],
   "role"=>[
     {"name"=>"Relation as Many", "operator"=>"rel_m_m"}
   ],
   "view_menu"=>[
     {"name"=>"Relation", "operator"=>"rel_o_m"},
     {"name"=>"No Relation", "operator"=>"nrel_o_m"}
   ]
  }
}
```

Without filters, the full list of permissions-resources shows this in result:

```
api/v1/security/permissions-resources/

"result"=>
  [{"id"=>1, "permission"=>{"name"=>"can_read"}, "view_menu"=>{"name"=>"SavedQuery"}},
   {"id"=>2, "permission"=>{"name"=>"can_write"}, "view_menu"=>{"name"=>"SavedQuery"}},
   {"id"=>3, "permission"=>{"name"=>"can_read"}, "view_menu"=>{"name"=>"CssTemplate"}},
   {"id"=>4, "permission"=>{"name"=>"can_write"}, "view_menu"=>{"name"=>"CssTemplate"}},
....
```

Have had few attempts at retrieving the nested `can_read` permissions, all failing so far:

```
api/v1/security/permissions-resources/?q=(filters:!((col:permission,opr:rel_o_m,value:can_read)))
The request was incorrectly performed

# not sure if the format is different for nested values
api/v1/security/permissions-resources/?q=(filters:(permission:!((col:name,opr:rel_o_m,value:can_read))))
The request was incorrectly performed

# without the extra internal bracket
api/v1/security/permissions-resources/?q=(filters:(permission:!(col:name,opr:rel_o_m,value:can_read)))
The request was incorrectly performed
```

I have tried a few other variations on the rison filters with no success.
Hopefully someone can point me to what I am missing?